# How to start a systemd service with complex arguments?

Tags: command-line, systemd, streaming

I want to stream video from a Raspberry Pi with a USB camera using [mjpg-streamer](https://github.com/jacksonliam/mjpg-streamer). Here is the commandline to start it from a bash shell:

```
./mjpg_streamer  -i "./input_uvc.so" -o "./output_http.so -w ./www -p 8000"
```

This works fine.

I have created the service file */lib/systemd/system/mjpg-streamer.service*:

```
[Unit]
Description=USB camera streaming service
Requires=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Environment=LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/pi/mjpg-streamer
EnvironmentFile=./mjpg-streamer.conf
ExecStart=/home/pi/mjpg-streamer/mjpg_streamer ${ARG1} ${ARG2}
StandardOutput=null
Restart=always
RestartSec=10

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Here is my environment file */lib/systemd/system/mjpg-streamer.conf*:

```
ARG1=-i "./input_uvc.so" 
ARG2=-o "./output_http.so -w ./www -p 8000"
```

The service starts, but the arguments are not being passed in correctly.

Comment: What about to write this command in a Bash Script and invoke it at ExecStart?

Comment: @Redbob Good idea. I'll give that a shot.

Comment: Another option would just be to add the arguments to the execstart line without them being as variables... unless those args are *changing* you wouldn't need to change the args.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up going down the path that Thomas Ward suggested.

```
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/mjpg_streamer -i 'input_uvc.so -d /dev/video0' -o 'output_http.so -w /home/pi/mjpg-streamer/www -p 8000'
```